# Cleaning up PHP arrays into one

Tags: php, arrays

```
array(1) {
  [0] => string(18) "AnotherTestSnippet"
}
array(1) {
  [0] => string(17) "Test Code Snippet"
}
array(1) {
  [0] => string(18) "AnotherTestSnippet"
}
array(1) {
  [0] => string(17) "Test Code Snippet"
}
```

How to convert the above array into this format using PHP?

```
array("AnotherTestSnippet","Test Code Snippet")
```

That is cleaning up and removing the duplicates. I have tried array_unique and and in_array but it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882649/delete-all-but-one-duplicate-record look at this

Comment: @RhoHappy you are linking to a MySQL question..

Comment: I think its not the answer, supposing the above result is a var_dump output of $myvariable. How would I manipulate $myvariable array so that it will output only the above converted and clean format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a loop and save only your unique enries:

```
<?php
$array = array (
    array( "AnotherTestSnippet" ),
    array( "Test Code Snippet" ),
    array( "AnotherTestSnippet" ),
    array( "Test Code Snippet" )
);

$new_array = array();

foreach ( $array as $value )
{
    if( !in_array( $value[0], $new_array) ) $new_array[] = $value[0];
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => AnotherTestSnippet
    [1] => Test Code Snippet
)
```

Comment: Thanks Dainis but it still not get the desired converted format..Probably because it contains several "array" word instead of having only one like in your example.

Comment: Can you edit your post us `var_export` instead?

Comment: @CodexMeridian Is this more like your array?

Comment: Yes this the var_export output:   array (
  0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet',
)array (
  0 => 'Test Code Snippet',
)array (
  0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet',
)array (
  0 => 'Test Code Snippet',
)

Comment: @Dainis, yes that's a single array variable in the script that I'm working, I'm really stuck on how to get a clean output from that..

Comment: @CodexMeridian does the edit work for you now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20232/discussion-between-codex-meridian-and-dainis-abols)

Answer (score 5):

Let's  call your arrays $array1 through $array4. Here is the solution:

```
$cleanArray = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4));
```

EDIT:

Now that I know you are starting with a single, multi-dimensional array, this is not the correct answer. The correct answer is the for loop given by Dainis Abols.

Comment: Yeah but there is only one PHP array variable involved with the above var_dump output.

Comment: Thanks David, but I only have one array variable involved with the above var_dump output, and I have tried array_unique(array_merge($myvariable)). It does attain the desired converted format.

Comment: Now I understand what you are asking. The correct answer has been provided by @DainisAbols.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your comments the var_dump output is wrong. You don't have four separate arrays, but one multidimensional array containing these arrays.

You can walk the array with [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/array_walk_recursive) using a closure like this:

```
$input = array(
    array('AnotherTestSnippet'),
    array('Test Code Snippet'),
    array('AnotherTestSnippet'),
    array('Test Code Snippet')
);

$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($input, function($a) use (&$result) {
    $result[] = $a;
});

$result = array_unique($result);
var_dump($result);
```

This echoes:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'AnotherTestSnippet' (length=18)
  1 => string 'Test Code Snippet' (length=17)
```

Comment: Thanks Acme, but I only have one array variable for example $myarrayvariable with the above var_dump output..I have tried array_merge($myarrayvariable) and it does not work..

Comment: Is that the full var_dump output?

Comment: Yes, a full var_dump output of a single PHP array variable..I'm stuck into this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing something? This can't be the output of a single variable. Is the single variable an array containing these 4 arrays as array elements?

Comment: This is the full var_dump output of a single array variable, someone edited it previously:   array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "AnotherTestSnippet"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "Test Code Snippet"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "AnotherTestSnippet"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "Test Code Snippet"
}

Comment: use `var_export` instead of `var_dump` - it's easier for us to put your code into our tests

Comment: @Acme, yes that's a single variable containing 4 arrays as array elements.

Comment: @Tim, thank you. This is the var_export output:   array (
  0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet',
)array (
  0 => 'Test Code Snippet',
)array (
  0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet',
)array (
  0 => 'Test Code Snippet',
)

Comment: @CodexMeridian I see, that was some important stuff. I updated my answer!

Comment: Thanks Acme, but the output is still the same.

Comment: I ran that in an isolated script and its output was what you are trying to achieve - I added the output in my answer. And the input array is the same as yours, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a = array("AnotherTestSnippet"); 
$b = array("Test Code Snippet"); 
$c = array("AnotherTestSnippet"); 
$d = array("Test Code Snippet");

$e = array_unique( array_merge( $a, $b, $c, $d ) ); 
var_dump( $e );
```

gives:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "AnotherTestSnippet"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "Test Code Snippet"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, however there is only PHP array variable involved that needs to be cleaned.

Comment: Your Q shows 4 separate arrays. For a single array `array_unique` works fine without the merge.

Comment: Thanks Tim,but array_unique still does not work.

Comment: because your question has the wrong structure. Please post the `var_export` of your actual structure

Comment: Hi Tim, this is the var_export output: array ( 0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet', )array ( 0 => 'Test Code Snippet', )array ( 0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet', )array ( 0 => 'Test Code Snippet', )

Comment: If that's the output of a *single* structure why are there no commas between the arrays?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20234/discussion-between-codex-meridian-and-tim)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the combination of [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) with [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$cleanArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, ... )
$cleanArray = array_unique($cleanArray);
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, but there is only one array variable.

Comment: I don't get you. Can you please share the full source code and what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to obtain a cleaned array both in values and keys:

```
$cleanedarray = array_values(array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3, $array4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<?php
 $a[]=array ( 0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet', );
 $a[]=array ( 0 => 'Test Code Snippet', );
 $a[]=array ( 0 => 'AnotherTestSnippet', );
 $a[]=array ( 0 => 'Test Code Snippet', );

foreach($a as $key=>$value)
{
    foreach($value as $key1=>$value1)
    {
        $new_array[]=$value1 ;

    }

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
echo "</pre>";
```