# Select and/or delete rows duplicates containing the same data

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I searched a lot and nothing could fit me. I am looking for a way to select or delete rows without removing everything. Check below to understand!

```sql
username ip_address

a 127.0.0.1
b 127.0.0.2
c 127.0.0.3
d 127.0.0.4 < duplicate keep
d 127.0.0.4 < duplicate remove
e 127.0.0.5
d 127.0.0.4 < duplicate remove
```

What it should select/delete:

```sql
username ip_address

d 127.0.0.4
d 127.0.0.4
```

EDIT:

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37254592/13158114) by making a new temporary table and duplicating the rows there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete all but one duplicate record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882649/delete-all-but-one-duplicate-record)

Comment: Also, it sounds like you should probably be putting a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column.

Comment: @Jesse It does not as i need to match the username and the ip_address, Not only 1 unique id.

Comment: @Tesla, you can have a constraint on a multiple columns, for example username,ip_address, or ip_address,username

Comment: @gview I'm not sure how to do that, Could you provide some example please?

Comment: ALTER TABLE your_table ADD CONSTRAINT your_table_username_ip UNIQUE KEY(username, ip_address)

Comment: Keep in mind you have to remove the duplicates in order to create the constraint.  After you've created it, it will disallow duplicate username,ip_address combinations

Comment: @gview and how i remove the duplicates?